# How may I statically implement Openssl for RSA encryption in my C project?

Tags: c, linux, openssl, static-linking

In normal cases we use `-lcrypto` as a flag for compiling a C program that has calls to OpenSSL functions, I wondered If I could use OpenSSL without the need to install the package itself on the system which is going to be used for running the executable. My target system does not have the openssl package installed to be able to run my program.

Comment: What do you want to use for the implementation of OpenSSL if you do not have the package installed and do not want to install it? Do you want to get the sources and build them into object modules yourself and link those statically into your program? Or get the sources, build them into a dynamic library (that is built only in your user account, not installed in the system area), and link that dynamically into your program?

Comment: I have openssl package installed for building, but I want to make it able to be executed in systems which don't have it installed

Comment: look into appimage, maybe.

Comment: If you statically link OpenSSL, then you're responsible for building and distributing a new binary every time OpenSSL releases a security update, instead of just having the distro update the package.  This is one reason we generally recommend dynamically linking such libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, change the following:

```
-lssl -lcrypto
```

With

```
-l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a
```

That will enforce the usage of the static libraries, which are integrated in the final executable (no need of them in the target system).